# Validação de usuário já existente em C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

A função verficaLoginExistente avisa que o login ainda existe, porém ainda assim continua para a próxima linha de código e cadastra. Quero que ela avise e retorne para cadastro de um novo nome. Meu banco de dados tem o cod_user como primary key ,usuario (string) e senha(varchar).

```
private bool VerificiarLoginExistente(string usuario)
    {
        bool resultado = false;
        string sql = "Select usuario From Usuario Where usuario = @usuario";
        Conexao cl = new Conexao();
        SqlConnection con = cl.conexao();
        SqlCommand cmdQry = con.CreateCommand(); 
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql))
            {
                command.Connection = con;
                command.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbUsuario;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    resultado = reader.Read();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nome de usuário já existente");
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        return resultado;
    }


    private void btnConfirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Conexao cl = new Conexao();
        SqlConnection con = cl.conexao();
        SqlCommand cmdQry = con.CreateCommand();

            string usuario, senha, confirmasenha;

            usuario = tbUsuario.Text;
            senha = tbSenha.Text;
            confirmasenha = tbSenhaConfirm.Text;

            if ((usuario == "") || (senha == "") || (confirmasenha == ""))
            {
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Campos obrigatórios");
                }
                return;
            }

            if((VerificiarLoginExistente(usuario))== true)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (senha == confirmasenha)
            {
                cmdQry.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Usuario (usuario, senha)" + "Values(@usuario,@senha)";

                cmdQry.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                cmdQry.Parameters.Add("@senha", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

                cmdQry.Parameters["@usuario"].Value = usuario;
                cmdQry.Parameters["@senha"].Value = senha;

                con.Open();
                cmdQry.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!");
                tbUsuario.Text = "";
                tbSenhaConfirm.Text = "";
                tbSenha.Text = "";
            }


            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Senhas não compatíveis !", "Aviso");
                tbSenhaConfirm.Text = "";
                tbSenha.Text = "";
                tbSenha.Focus();
            }



    }
```

Comment: qual tipo da coluna usuario? se for varchar tenta acrescentar aspas  assim `''@usuario''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que não é isso que você quer, mas se ao ocorrer uma exception significa o usuário já existe, então deve alterar o código para retornar algo no bloco `catch`. No .NET, ao ocorrer uma exception em um método com retorno diferente de `void`, o valor padrão do tipo definido no retorno é devolvido, no seu caso ao ocorrer a exception, o método retorna `false`:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Nome de usuário já existente");
     return true; // < ---- ADICIONE ESTE RETORNO
}
```

Se você diz que vê a mensagem que o usuário já existe significa que ocorreu uma exception no método `VerificiarLoginExistente`.

Acredito que haja algo errado com seu código, pois se a query e os parametros estão corretos, nenhuma exceção deveria ser lançada. Acredito que o erro esteja na linha:

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbUsuario;
```

Pelo seu código, entendo que `tbUsuario` seja um controle `TextBox`. Nesse caso, o correto seria passar o valor texto do controle e não a referência do objeto:

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbUsuario.Text;
```

Ou melhor ainda, de forma a usar o parâmetro do método que está sendo recebido sem ser utilizado:

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario;
```

Por fim, sugiro alterar a mensagem do MessageBox exibido no `catch`, pois se ocorrer um erro de *query* ou conexão com o banco, isso não significa que o usuário exista.

Comment: Fiz as alterações, agora deu certo, valeu, estava quebrando a cabeça aqui a horas !

Comment: Que bom! Se te ajudou e resolveu, por favor marque a resposta como aceita para que outros usuários possam se beneficiar também.